# Groupby a DataFrame into a new DataFrame with arange as index

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a question, simplified in this example. Consider this Pandas DataFrame, df_a:

```
df_a=pd.DataFrame([['1001',34.3,'red'],['1001',900.04,'red'],['1001',776,'red'],['1003',18.95,'green'],['1004',321.2,'blue']],columns=['id','amount','name'])

    id      amount  name
0   1001    34.30   red
1   1001    900.04  red
2   1001    776.00  red
3   1003    18.95   green
4   1004    321.20  blue
```

I would like to groupby this dataframe by summing the amount into a new DataFrame and create a new 'arange'-like index. This should be the result I would like to have:

```
    id      amount
0   1001    1710.34
1   1003    18.95
2   1004    321.20
```

But my efforts create a Series (I would like a DataFrame as result):

```
df_a.groupby(['id'])['amount'].sum()

id
1001    1710.34
1003      18.95
1004     321.20
Name: amount, dtype: float64
```

or create a new index based on the id column:

```
pd.DataFrame(df_a.groupby(['id'])['amount'].sum())

        amount
id  
1001    1710.34
1003    18.95
1004    321.20
```

I've also tried to pass the index parameter, but that doesn't work either:

```
pd.DataFrame(df_a.groupby(['id'])['amount'].sum(),index=df_a.index.values)

   amount
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
```

Does anyone have an elegant solution for this ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have a parameter as_index in groupby for that

```
df_a.groupby('id', as_index = False)['amount'].sum()
```

You get

```
    id  amount
0   1001    1710.34
1   1003    18.95
2   1004    321.20
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers!! A typical case of read-the-manual :-| sorry for that, but I coudn't find it while searching for index, re-index ,etc...

Answer (score 5):

You can try the following by adding `to_frame()` and `reset_index()`:

```
new_df = df_a.groupby(['id'])['amount'].sum().to_frame('amount').reset_index()
print(new_df)
```

Result:

```
     id   amount
0  1001  1710.34
1  1003    18.95
2  1004   321.20
```

If you only use `to_frame()` i.e. using

`df_a.groupby(['id'])['amount'].sum().to_frame('amount')`

it will keep index on `id` as following:

```
      amount
id           
1001  1710.34
1003    18.95
1004   321.20
```

Other way is to reset index on dataframe in your above code:

`new_df = pd.DataFrame(df_a.groupby(['id'])['amount'].sum()).reset_index()`

Output would be same as above:

```
     id   amount
0  1001  1710.34
1  1003    18.95
2  1004   321.20
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers!! A typical case of read-the-manual :-| sorry for that, but I coudn't find it while searching for index, re-index ,etc...

Comment: @student thanks mate! I was missing `reset_index()` and kept hitting issues.